# Inefficient calculation when looping through formulas

Tags: excel, vba

While I was trying to speed up my Workbook I incurred in this problem:

I've got several rows and columns to fill with formulas so I tried to make it all quicker by copying and pasting value after calculating formulas by slots. While this works easily on excel (doing it manually), when I do it with VBA it behaves like it's recalculating all the formulas, even if they're just values, and the calculating time grows every step.

Is there a way to avoid this strange behaviour?

PS: I've already tried to set calculation to manual but nothing changed since VBA seems to not care about it.

I know it shouldn't be necessary but here is the code:

```
Dim rw As Long, k As Long, i As Long, h As Long, l As Long
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'
Sheets("Report 1").Activate
    rw = Range(Cells(5, 3), Cells(5, 3).End(xlDown)).Count
        Sheets("match").Activate
k = rw / 5000
    h = 4
For l = 2 To 12
    For i = 1 To k
        Range(Cells(h, l), Cells(3 + rw - ((k - i) * 5000), l)).FormulaR1C1 = "=MATCH('BOM Str Parents'!RC,'Report 1'!c1,0)"
            Range(Cells(h, l), Cells(3 + rw - ((k - i) * 5000), l)).Value = Range(Cells(h, l), Cells(3 + rw - ((k - i) * 5000), l)).Value
        h = rw - ((k - i) * 5000) + 1
    Next i
Next l
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what precedents and dependents are related to the values you are inserting. A worksheet named **Report 1** suggests anything from statistical and subtotal formulas to an embedded chart and event macros like *Worksheet_Change*. Your code would benefit from reducing the calculation of the range to receive the formulas/values from three times to one as well as shutting down the 'big 3' application modes (e.g. *.ScreenUpdating, .EnableEvents* and *.Calculation*). Blocking the worksheets into **With ... End With** sections avoids the often ambiguous ActiveSheet parent referral. External references to the cells on **Report 1** should be temporarily broken.

```
    Dim rw As Long, k As Long, i As Long, h As Long, l As Long, rng As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    With Sheets("Report 1")
        rw = .Range(.Cells(5, 3), .Cells(5, 3).End(xlDown)).Count
    End With

    With Sheets("match")
        k = rw / 5000
        h = 4
        For l = 2 To 12
            For i = 1 To k
                Set rng = .Range(.Cells(h, l), .Cells(3 + rw - ((k - i) * 5000), l))
                rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=MATCH('BOM Str Parents'!RC, 'Report 1'!C1, 0)"
                rng = rng.Value2
                Set rng = Nothing
                h = rw - ((k - i) * 5000) + 1
            Next i
        Next l
    End With

    'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Those simple steps should speed up your calculation time significantly. `.Value2` can be used as we know that match is only going to return a long integer or an error. I don't know what calculation mode you started with so I left the return to `xlCalculationAutomatic` commented.

Actual results are going to depend greatly on what else is connected to the cells on **Report 1**.

**Addendum:**

I'm not sure if I have the row/column calculation or the range sizing entirely correct but the array sizing and orientation should be good and this runs a bit faster.

```
    Debug.Print Timer
    Dim h As Long, l As Long, v As Long
    Dim rws As Long, vRPT1a As Variant, vBOMstr As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    With Sheets("Report 1")
        vRPT1a = .Range(.Cells(5, 1), .Cells(5, 3).End(xlDown).Offset(0, -1)).Value
        rws = UBound(vRPT1a)
    End With

    With Sheets("match")
        h = 4
        For l = 2 To 12
            vBOMstr = Sheets("BOM Str Parents").Cells(h, l).Resize(rws, 1).Value2
            For v = LBound(vBOMstr, 1) To rws
                vBOMstr(v, 1) = Application.Match(vBOMstr(v, 1), Application.Index(vRPT1a, 0, 1), 0)
            Next v
            .Cells(4, l).Resize(rws, 1) = Application.Index(vBOMstr, 0, 1)
        Next l
    End With

    'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Debug.Print Timer
```

Comment: Jeeped, thank you for your code implementation, but the problem still persist:  each time i fill the 5000 rows range with formulas it gets slower and slower like excel is recalculating all the formulas above.
But we know they're just value and every step should take the same time.

Comment: @LeloucheVI - I've suggested a few times that there may be other dependencies that are slowing down the process but you've offered no indication of anything in that area. FWIW, Excel will slow down as it loads more memory doing tasks. Watch the *Processes* tab of *Task Manager* to see how memory usage grows while that runs. If speed is mission critical, load column A from **Report 1** into a dictionary object and all the values from **BOM Str Parents** into a variant array and process the whole thing in memory like [this](http://tinyurl.com/ntez24k) then drop the var array into **Report 1**.

Comment: In the "Report 1" sheet there are just columns with string values (no formulas, pivot,etc). I don't think the problem is related to what is in that sheet.
The problem is that when i try manually it takes 12 second for column, while launching the macro it takes 45 second. As I said it behaves like it's recalculating above formulas, while it shouldn't cause they're just values.
Anyway i tried to debug with F8 and that's where I've noticed this behaviou but even if VBA stops (like it's recalculating) if I force it pressing F8 again it goes ahed. 
Problem is I can't "force" during normal execution

Comment: @LeloucheVI - All `MATCH` returns to the **match** ws is the row number where the corresponding value from **BOM Str Parents** is located on **Report 1**'s column A. This is pretty useless information unless it is used by another formula like `INDEX` to actually locate a value. Select one of the values and check with Formulas ► Formula Auditing ► Trace Dependents. This will show you what other formulas are using the values in their calculations.

Comment: Yes,  MATCH formula results are  used by concatenated INDEX formulas at a later stage. Though I've been careful and I left no formulas in the workbook connected with those values. as I've been able to verify with the method you suggested.
I can guess,then, the problem is not within the Workbook.

Comment: @LeloucheVI - If there are no current dependencies then it sounds like the scope of the operation and the amount of available memory is what is holding you back. I can try to swap this over to array based calculation but the details are slim.

Comment: I adapted the array based macro but it just crashes.
Anyway, thanks for your effort and patience