# Is it possible to use Vlookup with a range?

Tags: excel-formula

I've not written any macros for some years so am rusty.

With Excel 2007 I need go through a whole column of data (assume it's column `A`) and for each cell in that column try to find the value in column `C` of another worksheet.

Can `Vlookup` do this or would I need to use another function?

Comment: You can a) write the formula into a number of rows at once and then revert the formulas to their returned values, b) loop through the rows and return the value one at a time or c) store the *lookup_values* in one array and the *table_array* in another and process them in memory then return the modified block of values back to the worksheet ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29621521/vba-odd-behaviour-in-formulas-calculating-time/29622804#29622804))

Comment: [See an example here](http://www.xlorate.com/vba-examples.html#Find%20Data%20in%20other%20Sheet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A basic example using a second sheet reference (Sheet2), with a range in column A:

```
=VLOOKUP(Sheet2!C2,A2:B5,2,FALSE)
```

Below is a working screenshot example:

[image]

**Useful Reference**

[VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/VLOOKUP-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65)