# Complex Vlookup Across Several Workbooks

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I need to search for some data cross-referencing 3 different workbooks.  Can this be done using `Vlookup` (nested perhaps) or would it need a VBA macro?

This is what needs to be done:

Workbook "**Sales**", Sheet "`Static`", `Column A` - loop through the whole column looking for each value in

Workbook "**Clients**", Sheet "`Sales`", `Column B` - if a match is found get the value in `column C`

Finally search for this value in Workbook "**Ledger**", `Sheet 1`, `column G` and then return the value from `column H` and copy this into the original workbook/sheet (**Workbook A**, sheet "`Static`") into `column J`.

Some of the data may be found, some not.

For reference I am using Excel 2007.

Comment: Yes, this is all possible using a `vlookup`. Was my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29649951/is-it-possible-to-use-vlookup-with-a-range/29650145#29650145) not enough to solve this? Please mark previous question complete if that was sufficient. Thanks.

Comment: @Matt - appreciate the help, What I need to do is more complicated than I first realised so my original question isn't relevant,I will mark it complete though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that u want value in J
can you try this formula in cell J1 of the First workbook(Sales)?

```
=VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(A1,[Clients]Sales!$B$1:$C$6,2,0),[Ledger]Sheet1!$G$1:$H$6,2,0)
```

P.S: Do not forget to change the range in the lookup array.

Hope this works.

Comment: One could add error clauses: IFERROR(...,"Data not found in Ledger/Sheet1") but this should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, this is working but it's very slow as I have over 100k lines of data - do you know how it might be speeded up?  Should I ask another question?

Comment: If you haven't tried [http://www.mbaexcel.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match-match/](index/match), that might help. There's a small learning curve, but I find index/match is quicker and better than Vlookup usually.  Also, what you could do, is paste the Vlookup formula to (say) 1000 rows. Let Excel calculate, then copy/paste Values over that range.  Then do the next 1000 rows, copy/paste values, and move on.  That might take a while, but you won't be calculating 100k+ formulas at once.